# ssh: execute a command before login

Tags: command-line, ssh

I am looking for a way to execute a local command when logging into a remote machine via SSH. (I want to stay logged in after the command has finished.)  In other words, I want to specify the command on my command line. It should be executed on the remote machine and then I should get the shell, as if I had logged in normally.

For instance, let's say, I want to mount `/home` on the remote machine before I get the shell. I would do something like this (which does not work well)

```
ssh mymachine.example.com 'mount /home ; /bin/bash'
```

In effect, I am looking for a way how to condense the following two commands into one:

```
ssh mymachine.example.com 'mount /home'
ssh mymachine.example.com
```

Does anybody have any idea how to do it?

**IMPORTANT**: I don't want to store the command-to-be-executed on the remote machine. It must be stored locally (perhaps it contains my password to de-crypt the encrypted home.)

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You are likely looking for the `-t` option for `ssh` which forces pseudo-terminal allocation - without that you are just directly connecting your terminal to standard input/output/error of the remotely running programs. Hence your command should look like this:

```
ssh -t mymachine.example.com 'mount /home ; /bin/bash'
```

Answer (score 3):

I recommend an alternate approach: [use a master connection](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/32984/multiple-ssh-sessions-in-single-command/33012#33012). First start a master connection that performs the mounting and then sleeps forever, then use slave connections that require no authentication and so are very fast.

```
ssh -M mymachine.example.com 'mount -o password=swordfish …; exec sleep 999999999'
ssh mymachine.example.com ls
```

Answer (score 1):

You could use the ssh's rc files.

File **~/.ssh/rc** is executed before de user's home becomes avalaible, so you can put all your stuff there.

The caveat is that these files reside on the server.

*man sshd* could be of help.