# Executing a remote command on SSH connection, before login

Tags: command-line, ssh, sshd

I am trying to find a way to execute a specific command when connecting to a server via SSH. By this I mean, the command will execute unconditionally on opening a connection, so this would preferably be run at the same time that a `Banner` option would be printed if set. I am not trying to run a command *after* logging in.

What I'm after, for example:

```
$ ssh bob@website.com
(Command essentially executed at this point, before the input prints.)
bob@website.com's password:
```

The reason I'm trying to do this is that I would like to run a short script which sends push notifications to my phone whenever a connection is made, regardless of whether I login or not. I had planned to use pam_exec, but this only triggers `auth` if a password is entered and enter is pressed, and the `account` and `session_*` modules only trigger on a successful login. If a connection is opened, but then closed such as when a user simply hits Ctrl+C, then the script will never be run.

Is there any method for doing this? I'm not finding much information on the subject.

Comment: possible duplicate of [ssh: execute a command before login](http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/88370/ssh-execute-a-command-before-login)

Comment: Not a duplicate, the linked question is about running a command before a shell is run, but still *after* successfully logging in.

Comment: If you do this you will be vulnerable to a denial of service attack. Any one that knows of this configuration can repeatedly connect to the ssh port, resulting in a barrage of messages being sent to your phone. This may be why there is no simple way to set this up.

Comment: If you still want to proceed (following my previous comment), then you could get the firewall to do it.

Comment: @richard: I am not too worried about this as the service I'm using rate limits notifications pretty heavily to one every 300 seconds. Connections to this particular box should be rare. I am thinking of making changes now though because of your warning. Thanks for pointing out the danger, I appreciate it.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can run `sshd` via `inetd`, with `inetd` running:

```
sh -c 'your-command; exec sshd -iD'
```

upon an incoming connection (see the caveat in `sshd(8)` though).