# Is there a way to run a privileged command upon successful SSH login (not necessarily with shell or PTY)?

Tags: linux, root, openssh, sshd

I'd like to run a privileged command upon successful SSH logins at the server's end. However, this has to be in the server configuration (`sshd_config` or anything else that cannot be manipulated or circumvented by the user) as I need this to be mandatory. That is, however restricted the system account used is, it needs to be able to manipulate a piece of data that requires superuser privileges (namely use `ipset add` conditionally - which I can script). Oh and I'd like to be able to access the contents of `SSH_CLIENT`, please - despite privileged execution. The command also must be unaffected by `ChrootDirectory`.

I am aware of `/etc/ssh/sshrc`, but that appears to be "client-side", i.e. it's being run by the user who is logging into the machine.

Does such a facility exist in OpenSSH? I am using version 6.6.

---

Also, the man page (`ssh(1)`) isn't all too clear about `sshrc`:

> `/etc/ssh/sshrc`
>   Commands in this file are executed by `ssh` when the user logs in, just before the user's
>   shell (or command) is started.  See the `sshd(8)` manual page for more information.

So does this mean it also runs whenever external commands (via `ForceCommand`) or subsystems like `internal-sftp` get invoked, despite restricting settings like PTY allocation or forcing a `chroot`? If so, I could resort to a restrictive `/etc/sudoers` entry if there is no other way at all.

**NB:** I am *not* using `inetd` for obvious reasons (see `sshd(8)`) as described [here](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/105289/5462).

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can do this using PAM and the [`pam_exec.so`](http://www.linux-pam.org/Linux-PAM-html/sag-pam_exec.html) module.

You simply add a line to `/etc/pam.d/sshd` to the 'session' section such as the following:

```
session    optional    pam_exec.so /usr/local/bin/ipset-ssh
```

Where `ipset-ssh` is some script you create.

The script will be run as root. You can get the client's IP address with the `PAM_RHOST` variable. You'll also want to check the `PAM_TYPE` variable as your script will be executed both on login, and logout. On login `PAM_TYPE` will be set to `open_session`. On logout it's set to `close_session`.

Here is the complete list of variables that I get from a simple test (I put `env > /tmp/pamenv` in script):

```
PAM_SERVICE=sshd
PAM_RHOST=127.0.0.1
GNOME_KEYRING_CONTROL=/home/phemmer/.cache/keyring-vJUUda
PAM_USER=phemmer
PWD=/
GNOME_KEYRING_PID=19742
SHLVL=1
PAM_TYPE=open_session
PAM_TTY=ssh
_=/usr/bin/env
```

Your script could be as simple as:

```
#!/bin/bash
[[ "$PAM_TYPE" == "open_session" ]] && ipset add whitelist $PAM_RHOST
```

Comment: Aha! Very nice. Thank you and of course +1.

Comment: I tried with `/usr/bin/env` and the `stdout` option and other than `PATH` and `LANG` I only get the `PAM_*` variables you mention. Also, the position in the config matters. I put it below the `pam_selinux.so` and `pam_env.so` modules.